Fantasy book about a boy, a different dimension, a girl, and another main character being a lizard
I remember this book I had read a long time ago.
It was about a boy going into a different dimension to find this girl who was going through something with her aunt/family. She went through, I think, a book into a different dimension/world/whatever you want to call it. Around the end, the boy did find the girl but also had to fight the antagonist. I think the antagonist did kill another main character that was, I think, a lizard.

In roughly which year did you read this?

Maybe 3 years ago? I had just randomly found it, but I do think it is a pretty old book.
